# Using FaceTime HD Camera without FaceTime

Tags: imac, camera, facetime

I have a Facetime HD camera in my new iMac but no one else I know has one. How can I test the HD capability of it? Photobooth doesn't take pictures in HD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Open Quicktime.
2. Choose File -> New Movie Recording.
3. On the little down arrow to the right of the record button, choose maximum quality. Also drag the record button holder to least obtrusive location.
4. Command-3 to fit to screen.

Answer (score 1):

QuickTime -> File -> New Movie Recording

Answer (score 0):

Skype?

Skype supports HD Video (assuming you have a fast enough connection)